# Fragment Map issues

Tags: android

I am trying to implement a google map into a contact list app I am building. I have ran the debugger it seems to be going to an exception at setContentView(R.layout.activity_contact_map);. I am unsure why or how to fix this. any advice would be greatly appreciated. It must be coded like this due to being a school project.

```
package com.example.mycontactlist;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;


import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationResult;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

public class ContactMapActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {


final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_LOCATION = 101;
GoogleMap gMap;
FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient;
LocationRequest locationRequest;
LocationCallback locationCallback;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_contact_map);


    fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    createLocationRequest();
    createLocationCallback();

    initListButton();
    initSettingsButton();
}

private void initListButton() {
    ImageButton contactList = findViewById(R.id.imageButtonList);
    contactList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(ContactMapActivity.this, ContactListActivity.class); // A mew Intent is created, the Intent's constructors requires reference to the current activity and know what activity to start
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}


private void initSettingsButton() {
    ImageButton contactList = findViewById(R.id.imageButtonSettings);
    contactList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(ContactMapActivity.this, ContactSettingsActivity.class); // A mew Intent is created, the Intent's constructors requires reference to the current activity and know what activity to start
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}


@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case PERMISSION_REQUEST_LOCATION: {
            System.out.println(grantResults.length);
            System.out.println(grantResults[0]);
            System.out.println(PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
            if (grantResults.length > 0 &&
                    grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                startLocationUpdates();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(ContactMapActivity.this,
                        "MyContactList will not locate your contacts.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

    }
}


@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 &&
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getBaseContext(),
                    android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) !=
                    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getBaseContext(),
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) !=
                    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }

}



private void createLocationRequest() {
    locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    locationRequest.setInterval(10000);
    locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
}

private void createLocationCallback() {
    locationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationResult (LocationResult locationResult) {
            if (locationResult == null) {
                return;
            }
            for (Location location : locationResult.getLocations()) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Lat: " + location.getLatitude() +
                        " Long: " + location.getLongitude() +
                        "Accuracy: " + location.getAccuracy(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        };
    };
}

private void startLocationUpdates() {
    if ( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getBaseContext(),
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission( getBaseContext(),
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) !=
    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationCallback, null);
    gMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
}

private void stopLocationUpdates() {
    if ( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getBaseContext(),
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) !=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
    ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission( getBaseContext(),
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) !=
    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    {
        return;
    }
    fusedLocationProviderClient.removeLocationUpdates(locationCallback);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    gMap = googleMap;
    gMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    try {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {

            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(ContactMapActivity.this,
                    android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) !=
                    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale
                        (ContactMapActivity.this,
                                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
                    Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.activity_contact_map),
                            "MyContactList requires this permission to locate " +
                                    "your contacts", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                            .setAction("OK", new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View view) {

                                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                                            ContactMapActivity.this,
                                            new String[]{
                                                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                                            PERMISSION_REQUEST_LOCATION);
                                }
                            })
                            .show();
                } else {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ContactMapActivity.this, new
                                    String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                            PERMISSION_REQUEST_LOCATION);
                }
            } else {
                startLocationUpdates();
            }
        } else {
            startLocationUpdates();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "ERROR requesting permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

}
```

here is the xml for activity_contact_map

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_contact_map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ContactMapActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/navbar_background"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButtonList"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:contentDescription="@string/button_to_display_a_list_of_contacts"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/paperclip" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButtonMap"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:contentDescription="@string/show_map_of_contact_location"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/placeholder" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButtonSettings"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:contentDescription="@string/show_settings"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/settings" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/linearLayout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is some of the errors I am getting

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.mycontactlist, PID: 8885
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mycontactlist/com.example.mycontactlist.ContactMapActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #45 in com.example.mycontactlist:layout/activity_contact_map: Binary XML file line #45 in com.example.mycontactlist:layout/activity_contact_map: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #45 in com.example.mycontactlist:layout/activity_contact_map: Binary XML file line #45 in com.example.mycontactlist:layout/activity_contact_map: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #45 in com.example.mycontactlist:layout/activity_contact_map: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:738)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:363)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:536)
        at android.app.FragmentContainer.instantiate(FragmentContainer.java:53)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:3553)
        at android.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:104)
        at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:7112)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:338)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:1067)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:995)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:959)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1121)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:680)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:532)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:696)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:170)
        at com.example.mycontactlist.ContactMapActivity.onCreate(ContactMapActivity.java:43)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

This is the exception it is jumping to:

```
private Activity performLaunchActivity(ActivityClientRecord r, Intent customIntent) {
        ActivityInfo aInfo = r.activityInfo;
        if (r.packageInfo == null) {
            r.packageInfo = getPackageInfo(aInfo.applicationInfo, r.compatInfo,
                    Context.CONTEXT_INCLUDE_CODE);
        }

        ComponentName component = r.intent.getComponent();
        if (component == null) {
            component = r.intent.resolveActivity(
                mInitialApplication.getPackageManager());
            r.intent.setComponent(component);
        }

        if (r.activityInfo.targetActivity != null) {
            component = new ComponentName(r.activityInfo.packageName,
                    r.activityInfo.targetActivity);
        }

        ContextImpl appContext = createBaseContextForActivity(r);
        Activity activity = null;
        try {
            java.lang.ClassLoader cl = appContext.getClassLoader();
            activity = mInstrumentation.newActivity(
                    cl, component.getClassName(), r.intent);
            StrictMode.incrementExpectedActivityCount(activity.getClass());
            r.intent.setExtrasClassLoader(cl);
            r.intent.prepareToEnterProcess();
            if (r.state != null) {
                r.state.setClassLoader(cl);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (!mInstrumentation.onException(activity, e)) {
                throw new RuntimeException(
                    "Unable to instantiate activity " + component
                    + ": " + e.toString(), e);
            }
        }

        try {
            Application app = r.packageInfo.makeApplication(false, mInstrumentation);

            if (localLOGV) Slog.v(TAG, "Performing launch of " + r);
            if (localLOGV) Slog.v(
                    TAG, r + ": app=" + app
                    + ", appName=" + app.getPackageName()
                    + ", pkg=" + r.packageInfo.getPackageName()
                    + ", comp=" + r.intent.getComponent().toShortString()
                    + ", dir=" + r.packageInfo.getAppDir());

            if (activity != null) {
                CharSequence title = r.activityInfo.loadLabel(appContext.getPackageManager());
                Configuration config = new Configuration(mCompatConfiguration);
                if (r.overrideConfig != null) {
                    config.updateFrom(r.overrideConfig);
                }
                if (DEBUG_CONFIGURATION) Slog.v(TAG, "Launching activity "
                        + r.activityInfo.name + " with config " + config);
                Window window = null;
                if (r.mPendingRemoveWindow != null && r.mPreserveWindow) {
                    window = r.mPendingRemoveWindow;
                    r.mPendingRemoveWindow = null;
                    r.mPendingRemoveWindowManager = null;
                }

                // Activity resources must be initialized with the same loaders as the
                // application context.
                appContext.getResources().addLoaders(
                        app.getResources().getLoaders().toArray(new ResourcesLoader[0]));

                appContext.setOuterContext(activity);
                activity.attach(appContext, this, getInstrumentation(), r.token,
                        r.ident, app, r.intent, r.activityInfo, title, r.parent,
                        r.embeddedID, r.lastNonConfigurationInstances, config,
                        r.referrer, r.voiceInteractor, window, r.configCallback,
                        r.assistToken);

                if (customIntent != null) {
                    activity.mIntent = customIntent;
                }
                r.lastNonConfigurationInstances = null;
                checkAndBlockForNetworkAccess();
                activity.mStartedActivity = false;
                int theme = r.activityInfo.getThemeResource();
                if (theme != 0) {
                    activity.setTheme(theme);
                }

                activity.mCalled = false;
                if (r.isPersistable()) {
                    mInstrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(activity, r.state, r.persistentState);
                } else {
                    mInstrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(activity, r.state);
                }
                if (!activity.mCalled) {
                    throw new SuperNotCalledException(
                        "Activity " + r.intent.getComponent().toShortString() +
                        " did not call through to super.onCreate()");
                }
                r.activity = activity;
                mLastReportedWindowingMode.put(activity.getActivityToken(),
                        config.windowConfiguration.getWindowingMode());
            }
            r.setState(ON_CREATE);

            // updatePendingActivityConfiguration() reads from mActivities to update
            // ActivityClientRecord which runs in a different thread. Protect modifications to
            // mActivities to avoid race.
            synchronized (mResourcesManager) {
                mActivities.put(r.token, r);
            }

        } catch (SuperNotCalledException e) {
            throw e;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (!mInstrumentation.onException(activity, e)) {
                throw new RuntimeException(
                    "Unable to start activity " + component
                    + ": " + e.toString(), e);
            }
        }

        return activity;
    }
```

Comment: It would be really helpful if you also posted the whole exception from debugger.

Answer (score -1):

it seems like the XML was missing class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"